# How to find the MAC address of a router?

Tags: router, mac-address

I'm trying to figure out the MAC address of my router.

This picture is of using the command ipconfig:

[image]

This picture is of using the arp -a command:

[image]

I see it says my IPv4 address is 192.168.1.114, so I go down to it in the arp -a command. However, there are many different MAC addresses for it. It also says the default gateway is 192.168.1.1, so my question is: Which one is my router MAC address? Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the ARP Cache entry for 192.168.1.1 is `c8d7.1914.f1d1`, which is likely the MAC address of the router interface to which you are connected.

According to your output of `ipconfig/all`, the MAC Address of your Network Interface is `844b.f522.6f98`.

Comment: Is that the router MAC address?

Comment: Yes.  Technically, the result of an ARP response for 192.168.1.1, which is likely your router.

Comment: Quick question: I did ipconfig /all, and under the one with the IPv4 address set to 192.168.1.114, there is an entry that says "Physical Address: 84-4B-F5-22-6F-98" Is that a router MAC address also?

Comment: No, that is your MAC address.

Comment: Well then which one is it? The arp -a one or the ipconfig /all one?

Comment: By your MAC address I mean the MAC of your own Network Interface Card or Wireless Adapter.  Every Ethernet Interface (wireless or Wired) has their own MAC Address (there are exceptions outside of the scope of this post).

Comment: Which one would I use if it says "You need the MAC address of the Wireless Router/AP you connect to with your 3DS"? (I'm trying to set up my router as a nintendo zone router.)

Comment: @Yoshi24517, home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. The good folks on [su] can help you set up your home network.

Comment: @Ron Maupin - Sorry, can't edit comments. I meant I'm not trying to set up my router for anything. I just need my MAC address. I have 2, listed above, but I don't know which one's which.

Answer (score 5):

You can issue `tracert 8.8.8.8` from your PC and find out the next hop IP address, that would be your next hop (gateway IP address) IP address, after that, issue command `arp -a`, and see that IP address mapped to which MAC address and that MAC address is the next hop (gateway).

Following is just for example.

```
C:\Users\>tracert 8.8.8.8  
Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]  
over a maximum of 30 hops:  
  1     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  192.168.1.1**  
  2     5ms      5ms      5ms   10.11.12.13   
  3  ^C

C:\Users\>arp -a  

Interface: 192.168.1.1 --- 0xb  
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type  
  192.168.1.1            c8d7.1914.f1d1     dynamic
```

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: I don't have 192.168.1.1 as an interface, but I do have it listed as an internet address as one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool if using Linux is `iw` for wireless and you can dump the connected router details using: `iw dev <device_name> station dump` where  is obtained from `ip a` and choose your active wireless name eg: `wlp3s0` - this may provide a number of devices, so you'll need to confirm you've identified the correct one.
Additionally there is `ip neigh show dev wlp3s0` which will provide the AP's connected to your router. Provides the same MAC details